# Font-size is set to EM but doesn't scale up for tablet?

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I've been converting [my forum](http://www.murraysworld.com/forum/) to responsive design using Bootstrap but I', seriously struggling with typography. Even though the font is in EM, on tablet devices, the font size ends up looking a lot smaller than it does on desktop.

So I'm having to mess around with media queries to increase the font-size for smaller devices. And it's a struggle. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: You should really provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rather than link your entire website.

Comment: Well for starters you have a media query that makes the font-size increase from 1.33em's to 2.1em's when it gets to 767px. Typography unfortunately does not scale and you will have to use media queries. There are methods with partial implementation but I prefer to stick to the facts. Set out device priorities and consider the intervals at which you'll need to alter them all.

Comment: Media query for 767px is based on Bootstrap's definition of mobile. I have to increase font-size for mobile otherwise it's too small. I then have to do this for tablets too, which has been tricky because I've struggled to create media queries that will trigger some Android tablets without triggering desktops on the same resolution.

On desktop, the font looks fine regardless of resolution. But not on tablets.

Comment: If it's causing you hassle and your still having to use media queries then why not just scrap bootstrap and implement media queries to control everything rather than attempting something that's probably going to wrap your brain for a considerable amount of time. I work on very high-profile commercial website development and we rarely use bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap isn't the issue for me. The issue is simply this: On desktop, the font-size looks fine as the resolution goes higher. On tablet, the font-size shrinks as the device's resolution goes up. That means I have to come up with ways to increase font-size for Android devices with resolutions that are also common on desktop, which is proving very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason why I was needing to increase font-size in the opposite direction (increase it for smaller devices).

It was all due to the initial-scale being below 1. Once I set it to 1 and figured out why I had to make it below 1 in the first place, all text issues were resolved.